# How to add a route app.domain.com to existing domain.com?

Tags: url

Currently have a website that's built on Next JS with a server on Express. I'd like to have a separate account dashboard section for users with a signed up account that's different from the main website for the public.

I currently have domain.com. I'd like to add a router for **app**.domain.com for the account dashboard section. How would one go about doing this?

Thanks y'all!